.Net framework 4.6 project with reference to 4.8 library
I need to maintain an old project targeting .Net Framework 4.6.
Currently, upgrading or changing the target version is not an option.
This project should reference a 3rd party library targeting.Net Framework 4.8.
I already know that this library does not contain any functionality specifically requiring .Net 4.8.
The warnings MSB3274 and MSB3275 appear as expected but compilation fails with CS0246: The type or the namespace...
I've extracted the code in question to a standalone 4.6 project which also fails to build targeting 4.6 but succeeds when targeting 4.8
Is there any chance to achieve what I am looking for?

"I've extracted the code in question to a standalone 4.6 project which also fails to build targeting 4.6" What errors do you see? Please also include the code that causes the errors.

4.8 was released 5 years ago, Windows Update ensured that nobody still has a machine that has 4.6 installed.  Nobody you could possibly support anyway.  So simply update the target version.

@HansPassant That's not always true. Most companies do not rely on automated windows updates, especially not for optional components.
